# Incorrect date value: '2016-06-05T00:00:00+05:30' for column '' in MySql

Tags: mysql, xml

I have windows forms application and mysql database.
And i use xml string to save detail part of a form here is my xml

```
> <DocumentElement>   <Table1>
>     <Qualification>fef</Qualification>
>     <University>fewfewf</University>
>     <Subject>fefwe</Subject>
>     <Grade>ffw</Grade>
>     <Duration>fef</Duration>
>     <StartDate>2016-06-05T00:00:00+05:30</StartDate>
>     <EndDate>2016-06-05T00:00:00+05:30</EndDate>   </Table1> </DocumentElement>
```

and in my stored procedure i have this code

```
 -- calculate the number of row elements. 
SET @v_row_count  := EXTRACTVALUE(QualificationsXML, CONCAT('count(','/DocumentElement/Table1)'));  
SET @v_row_iterator :=0;
SET @v_node := '/DocumentElement/Table1';

 -- loop through all the row elements    

WHILE @v_row_iterator < @v_row_count DO
    SET @v_row_iterator:=@v_row_iterator+1;
    SET @v_row := CONCAT(@v_node,'[',@v_row_iterator,']');

    INSERT INTO emp_qualifications VALUES (
        EmpNo,
        EXTRACTVALUE(QualificationsXML, CONCAT(@v_row,'/Qualification')),
        EXTRACTVALUE(QualificationsXML, CONCAT(@v_row,'/University')),
        EXTRACTVALUE(QualificationsXML, CONCAT(@v_row,'/Subject')),
        EXTRACTVALUE(QualificationsXML, CONCAT(@v_row,'/Grade')),
        EXTRACTVALUE(QualificationsXML, CONCAT(@v_row,'/Duration')),
        EXTRACTVALUE(QualificationsXML, CONCAT(@v_row,'/StartDate')),
        EXTRACTVALUE(QualificationsXML, CONCAT(@v_row,'/EndDate'))
    );

END WHILE;
```

But when i try to save its give me this error

> Incorrect date value: '2016-06-05T00:00:00+05:30' for column
>   'StartDate' at row 1

In my table structure i have two columns which i want to store StartDate and EndDate

> ```
> > `StartDate , Date,nullable 
> > `EndDate ,Date,nullable
> ```

can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with extra value but you should either remove the time zone info from the xml or change the column type to timestamp

Comment: @Peter4499 How can i remove the time part it's directly generate by the xml ?

Comment: @Rodham, it depends on how its generated. Failing that you can add a substring method on the Sql side

Comment: @peter4499 Thanks a lot,i removed time part of the date inside the SP.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the time part of the string by using

> SUBSTRING_INDEX(EXTRACTVALUE(QualificationsXML,
>   CONCAT(@v_row,'/StartDate')),'T',1),
>
> SUBSTRING_INDEX(EXTRACTVALUE(QualificationsXML,
>   CONCAT(@v_row,'/EndDate')),'T',1)

Thank you @peter4499

Comment: That's great would've answered properly but my sql instance is down and couldn't  test it. Glad you found your way

Comment: Thanks for sharing and solving yourself. Kuddos